# What is the difference between those two sentences (grammatically and in meaning)?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, word-order, noun-phrases

> 1. *An inappropriate TV show for children* should be banned on any type of channels.
> 2. *A TV show inappropriate for children* should be banned on any type of channels.

It seems to me that there is a very subtle difference between these two sentences, but I do not completely understand it. What is the difference?

Also, as the structure of the noun phrase different, it makes me wonder if they use different grammar structure. Are those different in grammar structure, or are they just the same?

Comment: No difference.  What does "from any type" mean?

Comment: Also, I'm confused about the grammar of sentence number 1. I thought that adjective (inappropriate) linked with prepositional phrase (for children) makes adjectival phrase (inappropriate for children) and has to come after the noun (a TV show) it modifies. But in sentence 1, adjective comes directly before the noun and the prepositional phrase comes after the noun, which puts the noun in the middle of the adjectival phrase. This seems to break the idea unnaturally, but I see that structure tons of times. So, why is that? And is there a name for that structure?

Comment: I edited it. I read it again and found my stupid mistake.

Comment: I withdraw my first comment.  That should read "little difference."  See my answer.

Comment: Um... where is the answer? I cannot see it.

Comment: You have to look very hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29557/discussion-between-sooeithdk-and-deadrat).

Answer (score 3):

Parse "An inappropriate TV show for children" as

> An inappropriate **[**TV show for children**]**

That is, any children's TV show that turns out to be wrong for children.  The prepositional phrase "for children" modifies "show."

Parse "A TV show inappropriate for children" as

> A TV show **[**inappropriate for children**]**

That is, any TV show, whether it's targeted for children or not. The prepositional phrase "for children" now modifies "inappropriate."  The "inappropriate" follows "show" because it's part of a reduced relative clause with the relative pronoun and verb elided:

> A TV show [that is] inappropriate for children.